# JavaScript method to determine correct path is confusing

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm learning algorithms and doing JavaScript exercise questions, and I don't understand how one reaches the correct answer for a particular algorithm.

The question provided in the exercise is:

> Have the function CorrectPath(str) read the str parameter being
> passed, which will represent the movements made in a 5x5 grid of cells
> starting from the top left position. The characters in the input
> string will be entirely composed of: r, l, u, d, ?. Each of the
> characters stand for the direction to take within the grid, for
> example: r = right, l = left, u = up, d = down. Your goal is to
> determine what characters the question marks should be in order for a
> path to be created to go from the top left of the grid all the way to
> the bottom right without touching previously travelled on cells in the
> grid.
>
> For example, the input `drdr??rrddd?` should ouptut `drdruurrdddd`

I've not found a solution on my own. I'm taking a look at a solution provided, and I'm bothered because:

A. pure functions are not used to manipulate values within the CorrectPath function (note the `addX()` and `addY()` methods contained within). I'm not convinced the solution provided is using best practices, especially coming from a functional programming background.

B. I don't understand how the steps taken, specifically in the `while` block and the succeeding `for` block, are taken to reach the correct answer and why sometimes the `missingLetters` array has letters remaining and other times not

The working solution provided is below

```
function CorrectPath(str) { 
    
    let x = 0, //start x coord
        y = 0, //start y coord
        missingLetters = []
    const unknowns = str.match(/\W/g)
       
    function addX() {
       while(x !== 4) {
           if (x > 4) {
               x--;
               missingLetters.push('l');
           } else {
               x++;
               missingLetters.push('r');
           }
       } 
    }
    
    function addY() {
        while (y !== 4) {
            if (y > 4) {
                y--;
                missingLetters.push('u');
            } else {
                y++;
                missingLetters.push('d');
            }
        }
    }

    //tallies current number of x and y movements
    for (let i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
        switch (str[i]) {
            case 'd': 
                y += 1;
                break;
            case 'u':
                y -= 1;
                break;
            case 'l':
                x -= 1;
                break;
            case 'r':
                x += 1;
                break;
        }
    }
    
    if (x > y) { addX(); addY(); }
    if (y >= x) { addY(); addX(); }
    
    while (missingLetters.length < unknowns.length) {
        var pos = missingLetters.length - 1;
        if (missingLetters[pos] === 'r') {x += 1; missingLetters.push('r'); addX()}
        if (missingLetters[pos] === 'l') {x -= 1; missingLetters.push('l'); addX()}
        if (missingLetters[pos] === 'd') {y += 1; missingLetters.push('d'); addY()}
        if (missingLetters[pos] === 'u') {y -= 1; missingLetters.push('u'); addY()}
    }
    
    var newStr = str.split('');
    for (var j=0; j<str.length; j++) {
      if (newStr[j] === '?') {
        newStr[j] = missingLetters.shift()
      }
    }
    return newStr.join('');
}
   
CorrectPath(readline());
```

Comment: The minimum steps to get from start to finish in this puzzle is 8: 4 right and 4 down. All addition moves are unnecessary but, if required by the pattern, have to be added in pairs: a right (+1, towards the goal) with a left (-1, away from the goal), or an up (-1, away from the goal) with a down (+1, towards the goal). The while adds moves based on those numbers. However I believe the strategy they use in the `while` loop for figuring out what needs to be added is haphazard so no wonder it's confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution I found

```
const dirMap = {
    u: { x: 0, y: -1 },
    r: { x: 1, y: 0 },
    d: { x: 0, y: 1 },
    l: { x: -1, y: 0 }
}

function CorrectPath(pathString) {
  const map = Array(5*5)
  return trace(pathString, map)
}

function trace(path, [...map], x = 0, y = 0, newPath = "") {
  const steps = path.split(""),
        nextMove = steps.shift()

  if (nextMove === undefined) {
    if (5 * y + x === (5*5-1)) return newPath
    return "Bad move"
  }

  if (nextMove === "?") {
    const moves = availableMoves(x,y,map)
    if (!moves.length) return "Bad move"
    for(let i = 0; i<moves.length; i++) {
      let move = moves[i],
          trySteps = [move,...steps].join("")
          res = trace(trySteps,map,x,y,newPath)
      if (!res || res === "Bad move") continue
      else return res
    }
    return "Bad move"
  } else {
    if (!canMove(nextMove, x, y, map)) return "Bad move"

    const pos = dirMap[nextMove],
          newX = pos.x + x,
          newY = pos.y + y
    newPath += nextMove
    map[5*newY+newX] = nextMove
    return trace(steps.join(""),map,newX,newY,newPath)
  }
}

function availableMoves(x,y,map) {
  const steps = []
  Object.keys(dirMap).forEach(z => {
    if (canMove(z,x,y,map)) steps.push(z)
  })
  return steps
}

function canMove(dir, xPath, yPath, map) {
  const pos = dirMap[dir],
        x = pos.x + xPath,
        y = pos.y + yPath
  if (x > 4 || x < 0 || y > 4 || y < 0) return false
  if (map[5*y+x] !== undefined) return false
  return true
}

CorrectPath(readline());
```